# Passing primitive data by reference in Java

Tags: java

is it possible to pass primitive data to a method as argument in java, without wrapping them into corresponding class objects ???

Comment: Just to be a bit pedantic as I completely understand what you're asking, nothing is passed by reference in Java, everything is pass by value.

Comment: Also, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113656/how-to-overcome-the-fact-that-primitives-are-passed-by-value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Java, it is not possible to pass primitives by reference.  To emulate this, you must pass a reference to an instance of a mutable wrapper class.

See [How do I pass a primitive data type by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319537/how-do-i-pass-a-primitive-data-type-by-reference/4319581#4319581) for more info on mutable wrapper classes.

Answer (score 19):

Don't do this, but since you asked....you can put them in 1 element lengthed arrays, and pass the array.

Comment: that won't modify the actual data only the array...

can we do it more abstractly ??

Comment: one if the none-practical answers I've ever seen. This's why everyone should try to read and study from books!!!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No Way!!

Long Answer: Primitive data are pass by value not by reference, why? Because they are not object.

"Primitive values do not share state with other primitive values." [Oracle Official Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Nevertheless if you still are intending to do this you may wanna take a look into [Wrapper classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html), each primitive has its homologue as a Wrapper

If you have a question when to use primitive or wrapper take a look to "[When to use primitive and when reference types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509025/when-to-use-primitive-and-when-reference-types-in-java)"