# In Java is it possible to create a procedure in the main method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, program-entry-point, procedure

Source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x,y,ir;
        x = 10;
        y = 5;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ir = scan.nextInt();

        switch(ir){
            case 1: y++;
                break;
            case 2: y--;
                break;
            case 3: x++;
                break;
            case 4: x--;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to repeat this part several times:

```
switch(ir){
    case 1: y++;
        break;
    case 2: y--;
        break;
    case 3: x++;
        break;
    case 4: x--;
        break;
}
```

But I don't wanna write it more than once. That's why I'd like write it like a procedure or a method. Is there any way to write a method which can modify a variable in my main method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600974/passing-primitive-data-by-reference-in-java?

Comment: No, you can't put one method inside another (short of some weird things with anonymous classes).  However, the *class* that contains the *main* method can have as many other methods as one wishes.

Comment: An alternative solution is to make `x` and `y` static fields so that you can modify them from another static method in `Test1` that you call from `main`.

Comment: No, you can't create a "procedure in the main method", but you could create a static method within Test1 class wch can be called from the main method

Comment: (The important thing to note here is that `main` is simply a particular method in a class (the `Test1` class in your case).  That class is like any other class and can contain other methods.)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can't since you are working with [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). If you use a reference type, however, you can modify its contents when passing it to another method.

The solution to your problem is to either define your variables on a higher level (which would be instance scope here) or to pass a wrapper type to your method (for example `int` has the corresponding reference type `Integer`). The latter approach is something I would not suggest you to do though.

Another solution, which is perhaps more interesting, is to just wrap it in [a loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) inside your `main` method. It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do but you should definitely see if it can be solved like this.

Note that you are working from your `main` method so any method you want to call would have to be `static`. Proper code wouldn't do this but instead work with an object and instance methods.

But no, you cannot nest methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by creating a class inside your main method which provides that functionality.

A quick example:

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;        

        class MyClass {
            public int x;
            public int y;

            MyClass() {
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            }

            public void doSomething() {
                x++;
                y++;
            }
        }

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.doSomething();
        myClass.doSomething();
        myClass.doSomething();

        x = myClass.x;
        y = myClass.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, it's not a beautiful solution and best avoided.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could create a class like this inside a method. I know about anonymous inner classes of course, but this was a new one for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with static variables. 
My form:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class a{
    public static int x = 10;
    public static int y = 10;


    public static void lep(int ir){
        switch(ir){
            case 1: y++;
                break;
            case 2: y--;
                break;
            case 3: x++;
                break;
            case 4: x--;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ir = scan.nextInt();
        lep(ir);
        System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y);

    }
}
```

Solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's not exactly what you asked for, but I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: The aim of the question was: how can I modify a variable which is in my main method? Sorry if the question was bad or not understandable, but you could also help me.